# ASP.NET MVC3 - Entity Framework: Many-to-many relation (news and categories)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I want to create categories for news. It will be many-to-many relation. How do that properly? I have created two classes:

```
public class News
{
    public News()
    {
        this.NewsCategories = new List<NewsCategory>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }  
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<NewsCategory> NewsCategories { get; set; }
}

public class NewsCategory
{
    public NewsCategory()
    {
        this.News = new List<News>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<News> News { get; set; }
}
```

But EF create just two tables...without Join table. I have created also custom DbInitializer:

```
public class TouristGuideDBInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TouristGuideDB>
{
    protected override void Seed(TouristGuideDB context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);
        context.NewsCategories.Add(new NewsCategory { Name = "Default" });
        context.NewsCategories.Add(new NewsCategory { Name = "Second" });
        context.News.Add(new News { Date = DateTime.Now, Text = "asasdfas fasdfa sdf asf asf", Title = "Hello world" });
        context.SaveChanges();
        var news = context.News.First();            
        var cat = context.NewsCategories.Where(r => r.Name == "Default").Single();            
        news.NewsCategories.ToList().Add(cat);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But it just add one news and two categories...without relationships...
How it should be done properly (the relations)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ICollection<T>` for navigation properties.

Comment: ok, it helps - I have Join table (NewsCategoryNews), but still do not know how to manage this relation... news.NewsCategories.ToList().Add(cat); didn't add anything to join table...when I add it manualy, I can not get data using news.NewsCategories.ToList().First().Name

Comment: Don't use `ToList()`; you're adding to a temporary list created by` ToList()`.  EF will only add it to the other end of the relation when you save, or (IIRC) if you make the property `virtual`.

Comment: It can help you: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx